C++ standard requirements on Allocator and AllocatorAwareContainer?
I've been implementing what is essentially a feature limited std::vector, which is allocator aware. However, I've noticed something in the definition of the C++ Standard (17, 20, and working draft) which gives me pause. Specifically, the optional construct function of allocator does not have semantic requirements, nor is it added for allocator aware containers. The lack of requirements leads me to worry about the effect of custom construct. The main issue here is that strong exception guarentees' are (to my thinking) impossible to give in some cases. Namely, the use of construct to move objects (which use allocators) may change their allocator (due to using allocator construction). However, this may lead to a throwing move assignment when trying to roll back changes due to a later exception in the operation.
What assumptions can be made about allocators in this regard?

Don't spam tag versions, I removed some of them

My impression (without references to the standard) is that the std::vector does not attempt recovery from a throwing move operation. The already moved objects might be lost, and that is the risk you accept when storing "hard to move" objects in a vector.

std::move is a one way street. An moved-from object is in a valid but unspecified state. To safely "roll back" you'd probably need to store actual data somewhere in a memory pool (hence your custom allocator), and then objects pretty much just point at that data without it moving around (only the owner changes). The pool allocator would then need to own the complete lifetime of that data.
